# Обязательный аргументы метода класса

Tags: php, ооп

Будет ли срабатывать метод класса, если не указать все обязательные аргументы этого метода? или будет возвращать false/exit?

Comment: интересное такое программирование было бы с возвратом `false`, `if($patient->isAlive()) $morgue->move($patient)`, забыл аргумент и всех к праотцам

Answer (score 0):

Если аргументы не заданы заранее - типо

```
public function lol($kek = 0)
{
    print_r($kek);
}
```

То будет ошибка, из серии - передано `0` аргументов, ожидается `1`.